# Reducing Text Input Area of UITextView

Tags: ios

I have a `UITextView` of size W,H. By default the width of its Text Input Region is equal to the width of the `UITextView`.
I want to reduce the width of the Text input region only, keeping `UITextView's` width same. Basically, I want to achieve similar to the methods `drawTextInRect:` or `editingRectForBounds:` of `UITextField`

How can I do the same thing for `UITextView`?

Comment: Did you consider limiting the character numbers in text field?

Comment: I don't want to limit the character numbers, all I need is to reduce the contentOffset width of uitextview. I tried to reduce that, but it didn't work.